# ComponentWillUnmount is called before componentDidmount

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I having a component called PAGE2 from which I am coming back to component PAGE1. Now when I move from PAGE1 to PAGE2 with different props I am seeing PAGE2 with old values (Here componentDidMount is not invoked which contain fetchListValues function)

I am coming from PAGE 2 to PAGE 1 using
navigation.navigate('PAGE1');

```
  componentDidMount = () => {
    // in page 2
    this.fetchChats();

    this.backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
      "hardwareBackPress",
      this.handleBackPress
    );
  };

  handleBackPress() {
    console.log('Back pressing', this.props.navigation);
    this.props.navigation.navigate('PAGE1');
    return true;  
  }

   componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log('Hitting component will unmount');
    BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", 
     this.handleBackPress);
  }
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code - nobody can help if they can't see what you've written.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('PAGE1');
//instead of this use the one below
this.props.navigation.goBack();
```

Navigating not unmounting PAGE2, so related function not called.

Comment: I tried that it is taking to page 0 thats why i used navigate

Comment: goBack() goes to previous route in stack. I think you should inspect your screens and navigations.

I want to declare that componentDidMount not called every screen changes. I was also expecting this when I first used it. You should take a look to focus and blur events of react-navigation.